# React в docker не обновляется

Tags: reactjs, docker

У меня есть приложение на nodejs и react, которое лежит в контейнере и имеет внутри контейнера следующую структуру: папки API и APP, внутри каждой лежит Dockerfile, в корневой папке лежит файл docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    build: ./API
    container_name: back
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
  app:
    build: ./APP
    container_name: front
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

Запускаю приложение командой docker compose up -d

Запуск проходит успешно, я могу зайти на страницу и все работает отлично, кроме того, что при обновлении кода никаких изменений нет, я пробовал останавливать контейнер и запускать снова, но это не помогает, как разрабатывать в контейнере?

P.S. Видел подобный вопрос, но ответ на него мне не помог, там говорилось в package.json изменить start c react scripts start на WATCHPACK_POLLING=true react-scripts start

Comment: контейнер собрался с кодом. Где вы затем меняете код и как ожидаете получить изменения в контейнере?